# How to not render a page when the page is built with ACF?

Tags: wordpress

I'm building a Wordpress site and I'm using the ACF plugin to allow administrators to build pages based on different blocks created in ACF.

The issue I'm having is that now we want some pages to be private, but even when I set a page to private, the content still appears. I figure this has something to do with the way I have the template setup.

Here's the page template;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes() ?>>

<?php get_template_part('head') ?>

<body>

<?php get_header() ?>

<?php
/*************************************************
 *  Show Additional Content modules from ACF
 ************************************************/
if ( have_rows('content') ) {
    while ( have_rows('content') ) : the_row();

        $modulePath = 'templates/content-modules';
        $layout = get_row_layout();
        if (file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/' . $modulePath . '/' . $layout . '.php')) {
            get_template_part($modulePath . '/' . $layout);
        }
    endwhile;
}
?>

<?php get_footer() ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Were the ACF content is currently rendered, I don't want that to be rendered when a page is private, and instead I'd like the password field to appear.

How can I do that?

EDIT:

I can get the password field to appear if I add the following into the template somewhere, but this doesn't prevent the ACF stuff from appearing.

```
<?php
/* Start the Loop */
while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
    the_content();
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: When you're checking the page while it's set to Private, are you checking it while you're still logged into Wordpress? If so, either log out, or try checking the URL in Incognito to confirm that content is still showing up.

Comment: No, I'm logged out when I'm checking the page.

Answer (score 0):

Check the status of the page & based on the status you can show/hide the content

```
if ( get_post_status ( $ID ) == 'private' ) {

       //Display ACF fields

   } else {

echo "The page is restricted"
   }
```

Comment: You will get Page id from

```
$ID = get_the_ID();

Comment: How do I check whether or not the user is allowed to see the page though?

Comment: if you se the page as "private" this piece of code should be all you need to achieve the result u're looking for